# How can I clear the screen using a graphics object?

Tags: java

I need to clear the screen after using a grid of

```
g.drawRect(x * 32, y * 32, 32, 32);
```

But I need to dispose of what was there before that frame. Is there a 'clear' method, or something like that?

Comment: clear the entire screen? using (0, 0, width, height)

Comment: Call super.paintComponent and let the paint chain deal with it

Comment: Without any further context, I'd suggest taking a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to understand how painting in Swing works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clear everything that was painted by the previous call of paintComponent(), then at the beginning of that method, add this call:

`super.paintComponent(g);`

Otherwise, you could draw a large rectangle over the entire pane, to cover everything up.